# back link not working in Phonegap and Framework 7

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework 7 UI for a Phonegap application.

I have 3 pages(page1->page2->page3) with href from one to the next.
In each page I have a top navbar with back link:

```
<a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a>
```

When I try to get back from page3 to page2 I have no problems. When I try to get back from page2 to page1 it works only if I didn't get from page2 to page3 earlier.

For instance, this steps will work fine:

```
Page1->Page2->Page3->Page2
Page1->Page2->Page1
```

But this will fail in getting from page2 back to page1 (the second back):

```
Page1->Page2->Page3->Page2->Page1
```

I tried to fire mainView.router.back() in the code but I get the same results.

Someone is familiar with this issue?

Comment: I had a similar issue, where the back button did not work. The reason for this was that there was an error on the page (Page1), which only occured after visiting a certain page(Page3). So, I think we need more info. What does page3 do and can it influence the content of page1 (for example, database changes etc)? Do you have the caching enabled for these pages?

Comment: @TimV, Thank you very much! The problem wasn't on page3, but I manage to find it out by stripping the code page by page. Eventually it was misplaced "login-screen".

Answer (score 0):

After removing all elements and scripts, I added them one by one and I found out that the problem was on page1.
I had a login-screen [as described here](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/login-screen.html#.VnlDzpN94U4).
Unfortunately, I misplaced the login-screen div element - it should be a direct child of the body element.